# codecademy Practice Makes Perfect digit_sum

Tags: python

The purpose is Write a function called digit_sum that takes a positive integer n as input and returns the sum of all that number's digits.

For example: digit_sum(1234) should return 10 which is 1 + 2 + 3 + 4.

(Assume that the number you are given will always be positive.)

https://www.codecademy.com/zh/courses/python-intermediate-en-rCQKw/0/4?curriculum_id=4f89dab3d788890003000096#

Your function fails on digit_sum(1000). It returns 12 when it should return 1.

If I put the dig=[] upper on the def digit_sum, the course occurred alarm that "digit_sum(1000) result is 12 instead of 1" , but I ran this program on my local notepad+powershell, it ok , the result is right.

after that I put the dig=[] into the first line of function , then it worked normally .

I didn't get 2 points....

1. What's the difference between "dig=[]" inside/outside the function
2. if the "dig=[]" outside the function is wrong , why I can ran it successfully on my local....?

Thanks for guys to help me......

```
dig=[]
def digit_sum(n):
    u=str(n)
    for i in u:
        dig.append(i)
        s=0
        for number in dig:
            int(number)
            s=s+int(number)
    return s
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the difference between inside/outside is **locality**. When you put `dig` outside, you create a global list. From there, you're constantly *appending* to that- the list is never cleared! So if I run `digit_sum(1234)`, I properly get 10. If I immediately thereafter run `digit_sum(1000)`, `dig==['1','2','3','4','1','0','0','0']` which will then add all those and mess up.

If you do dig = [] *inside* the function, it creates a *new, local* list - it isn't being changed each time, it's a new empty list for each rotation.

The reason you're getting it correctly sometimes is because the function has *side effects*, so order of calling and history of calling matters. Try to avoid side effects of functions- either don't alter a list, or copy the list>alter that copy>`return` the copy if you want to assign the new list (or just work with the new list.)

Comment: Ok....I got it...the result of last time rotation will be left in the global var ...........thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

```
def digit_sum(n):
  n = str(n)
  total = 0
  for i in n:
    total += int(i)
  return total
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like :

```
def digit_sum(n):
    dig=0 # this is the result os the sum
    number=str(n) #transform the number into string so we can iterate 
    for i in range(len(number)):
        dig=dig+int(number[i]) #transform the char to int
    return dig #return the sum
```

I take the number (eg 123) and I transform it to a string so I can get the length of the string (the number of digit). Then I simply add them (after transforming them to integers) and return the result

`dig=[]` means you declare an array variable which is not what you want here. If it is declared in the function it means that when the function ends, the variable "disappeared", you won't be able to call it back. It'll only exist IN the function. If it is before the function, the variable exists to the end of your program.

Your aptenpt isn't correct. You want to populate your array with the number THEN sum them. In fact when you assign a number to your array `dig` you are summing then. For exemple 123 will sum : 1 then 1+2 then 1+2+3

Comment: So actually if I put the dig outside the function, the last time result will be left in the dig , right？

Comment: Exactly because the variable declared outside the function doesn't end at the end of the function

Comment: And to continue, every time you run it `dig` will keep getting longer and longer- not just the last result stays, _every single prior input_ stays. If you put in 10 sets of 4-digit numbers, `dig` will contain 40 numbers.

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer is all right. 
Just to focuse your attention so that you could avoid mistakes in the future:
When you write:

```
u=str(n)
    for i in u:
        dig.append(i)
```

you don't append the digits of the number to the dig. Instead you add digits 0, 1 ,2 ,3 .. so on. Exactly them however the number may be. Because the For Loop iterates from the beginning to the end of a string, a list etc. and the variable after the word For is just a counter - starting from 0 and ending at the end of the object.
Tha is why the answer of Hearner is right: 
the number[i] 's are summed not the i's.

```
for i in range(len(number)):
    dig=dig+int(number[i])
```

Comment: Yes. thanks so much for your patient answer...nice weekend