# Python codecademy digit_sum

Tags: python

the task was discussed in 
[codecademy Practice Makes Perfect digit_sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37948737/codecademy-practice-makes-perfect-digit-sum)

Where you need to sum the digits of a positive number.
I use the string way to decide the task (not the floor dividing).

My code is

```
def digit_sum (n):
    total = 0
    for digit in range(len(str(n))):
        total += int(n[digit])
    return total

number = raw_input("Please print a long number: ")    
print digit_sum(number)
```

It works all right with 1001 as well as with 434.

However, the program says:
Does your digit_sum function take exactly one argument (a positive integer)? Your code threw a "'int' object has no attribute '**getitem**'" error.

What can be wrong when the code is working?

Thanks!

Comment: You beat me to it!

Comment: Your program is fine. Possibly, the checker tries to verify that the input to `digit_sum` is an actual integer, instead of a string. Try changing the last line to `print digit_sum(int(number))` and see how that goes. (You're casting to `str` later on anyway, though you need to cast again when doing `n[digit]`, since that won't work now.)

Comment: if your "n" is an integer, then 4th line `n[digit]` is wrong - you can't index an integer, you need to convert it to string first. there are good examples how to do this faster and nicer below

Answer (score 1):

you did not convert n to string, so when you call n[i] it will raise exception

```
def digit_sum(n):
    return sum(  int(i) for i in str(n) )
```

Comment: No need for the brackets; `sum` will take a generator expression which, when it's the only argument to a function, reuses the function call parens: `sum(int(i) for i in str(n))`. Or for extra speed (only because `int` is a built-in function; normally `map` is slower than listcomp/genexpr), `sum(map(int, str(n)))`.

Comment: @galaxyan, `raw_input` provides a string. What is the need to convert it into string again? Also, the OP's code is working fine.

Comment: @SilentMonk from error message, it is not what po post

Comment: @ShadowRanger, the task was to create a function that takes an int as an input. Of course one can deal with this task by means of floor division but the string way was clearer to me.

Answer (score 0):

Evert, Jerzyk, Galaxian, thanks for the comments. Thanks for you I saw it: I casted n to str only in one place (3rd line) and thought that this was enough since the 4th line is inside the for loop. I edited the code to

```
def digit_sum (n):
    total = 0
    n = str(n)
    for digit in range(len(n)):
        total += int(n[digit])
    return total

number = int(raw_input("Please print a long number: "))    
print digit_sum(number)
```

And now it works!

Galaxian, ShadowRanger, thanks for your short code, I tried it and it' fine!
I haven't caught yet this brief way of coding. By the way I searched for info about map function and found this:[explanation on zip, map, lyambda](http://ninjaside.info/blog/ru/funkcii-map-i-zip-i-lambda-python/)

Comment: FYI, `for digit in range(len(n)):` then indexing `n` is a C way of doing things, not at all Pythonic. Just iterate `n` directly and avoid indexing. `for dig in n: total += int(dig)`